# Unexpected behaviour of d3 rangeRound

Tags: d3.js

I am using this scale:

```
scale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .rangeRound([0, 10])
```

I don't understand why `scale(5)` returns `1`.
Shouldn't numbers up to 9 return 0?

Also this seems odd:

```
scale(27): 2
scale(28): 3
```

All I want to do is take an input integer and return an integer from 0 to N (divided in equal parts!)

I guess my question is *"How can I fix my scale?"*

Comment: The behaviour you're seeing regarding `scale(5)` is the expected one given how `Math.round()` works. Also, `scale(27)` returns 3, not 2. Can you provide a demo returning 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution that works!

```
scale = d3
    .scaleQuantize()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range(d3.range(10))
```

```
// scale(9): 0
// scale(10): 1
// scale(27): 2
// scale(28): 2
```